# C Just Delete Some Part Of File

Tags: c, linux, file

I have two files. I want to copy source file to destionation file. If they are different, then I just want to copy different line not all file. In the below case, two line are same, but destination has extra line. How can I just delete last line of destination file?

For example:

```
Source File:

test1  
test2

Destionation File:

test1
test2  
test3
```

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: linux operating system

Comment: Do you need to program it in C, or is the end result all you need? If you don't care about the logic, then piping the files to the linux command `uniq` may be a good choice.

Comment: What about rewriting the file while excluding the missing section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On POSIX systems, if you want to delete some ending bytes in a file, you could use [ftruncate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html)

There is no portable way to remove bytes in the middle of a file.